# Insert script tag in top body from an iframe and execute it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have an ad  tag that is running inside a Friendly (same domain) iframe (served via Google DFP). At the current state the code inside the iframe executes wonderfully inside it, problem is that I want that code to be run inside the top DOM and not insde the iframe.

I've used `insertAdjacentHTML` to insert the code into the top DOM but it isn't executing like I would hope to (not even the console.log I inserted at the end).

Here's the code I've used inside the iframe to insert it in the top body:

```
var tag = '<SCR'+'IPT type="text/javascript" SRC="...snip..."></SCR'+'IPT><scr'+'ipt>console.log("hi");</scr'+'ipt>';

var topBody = top.document.querySelector("body");
topBody.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',tag);
</script>
```

I've looked at similar questions here on S.O but most of them only handle "same document" use cases and not "cross document same domain" use cases.

Comment: `<iframe id="frame"></frame>...document.getElementById('frame').contentDocument.body.appendChild(tag)`

Comment: This approach gets tricky because I can't identify consistently the iframe, meaning it doesn't always have the same ID. if I do `top.document.querySelector("body").contentDocument.body.appe‌​ndChild(tag)`, would it achieve the same result?

Comment: use `queryselector` to find the frame

Comment: @Daniel_L Tried it with an existing iframe in the page with no success: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined(…)`

Comment: post all your html

Comment: @Daniel_L Nevermind, I was selecting the wrong element. Still, appendChild is waiting for a "Node" type object, which isn't the case since I'm passing a string to it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120142/discussion-between-ddrjm-and-daniel-l).